# I have an excel pivot table. How do I change the data source using python?

Tags: python, excel, pivot, pivot-table, openpyxl

Every month, for example, the content of the source for the pivot table changes. How do I change the data source (file, sheet and range) and update the pivot table using python?

I found only "how to update a pivot table", but I still need to change the source before that, and then update. Thanks in advance)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can try. First read the Openpyxl documentation https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pivot.html?highlight=pivot. The current reference would be in **pivot.cache.cacheSource.worksheetSource.ref**